# Install Ubuntu on new computer build

Tags: system-installation

I am going to build a new computer and don't want to install/buy Windows as the OS.  I'd like to install the latest version of Ubuntu.  Is this possible or will still need to have a copy of Windows?  And if it's possible do I just follow the Ubuntu installation guide as normal?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  Just download the version (and flavor - Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc) that you want.  Check the MD5Sum 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
Burn the ISO to a CD or flash drive at the lowest speed possible.  Boot from the result and try all the applications before you install.  If everything works choose to install.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is an operating system.  It **replaces** other operating systems like Windows.  So no, there is no need for Windows prior to installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible to install ubuntu without installing windows.Ubuntu can replace windows.And you can follow the ubuntu installation guide as normal

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm building a new computer and will be needing a OS.